# Attempting to open TSV file in Libreoffice Calc results in being opened by Writer

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice

I have been working with TSV files for months, but I have one file that refuses to be opened in LibreOffice Calc. It instead brings it up in writer. This behavior is consistent across command line and from the file open dialog.

I am using LibreOffice 3.5.7.2

One line of the file being opened looks like this:

```
-1.7707604  -0.50868493 -1.0049824  -1.0982082  -1.5262277  -1.505284   -1.0780258  -1.2065934     #1 cheat: chess with friends edition #1 Cheat Words With Friends Edition <page>\n <title>df75f611bd836c15388067608d87463b</title>\n <ns>0</ns>\n <id>0</id>\n <timestamp>?</timestamp>\n <text >\n#1 Cheat Words With Friends Edition\n\n??? AS SEEN ON TV! Don&apos;t just win at Words With Friends, DESTROY your opponents!\n\nWin every single game even if THEY are the ones that are cheating. The app they are using to cheat does not stand a chance against #1 Cheat!\n\n#1 Cheat is completely automatic. This means that your Words With Friends game is scanned for you and there are absolutely no letters to input. Check out the YouTube video to see the magic in action:\n\nhttp://tinyurl.com/3wco9wm\n\n#1 Cheat is the MOST EFFECTIVE word finder on the App Store hands down! Other apps claim to find the highest scoring words. They are liars!\n\n#1 Cheat is compatible with Words With Friends, Scrabble, and Friendle.\n\n* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * \nThe creators of this app are in no way affiliated with the authors of any app, game, licensor, or trademark mentioned in this description or in the app.\n\nBug Fixes\n </text>\n</page>
```

Comment: More information is required to answer this question. Size of that TSV? Looks like the "string" part cause problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently libreoffice has changed its behavior and now opens .tsv files as write files. I had to rename to .csv.